Websockets vs socket.io for Flask
Can we use Websockets for flask application instead of flask-socketio?
I created a trading project in which i am using websockets to build socket connection between client and the server. next, i wanted to display the data on a websie. so, for that i want to use Flask. BUt, i am confused as to which library i should use.
I will be thankful if someone can help me with this.

Which you should use is highly dependent on what you need to do with the websockets. However, unless there is a specific feature of the Websockets package that isn't in flask-socketio I would use flask-socketio. Its syntax mirrors Flasks and plays very well with it.
